# Fetch API Response Code Differs from Network Tab Response Code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm creating a React component which is intended to check for updates to a privacy policy page, based on whether the page is cached. I'm having two issues -

1. The response code shown by the Response object differs from the response code shown in the network tab.
2. Less critically, the request is being sent twice, and I'm not exactly sure why. This might be a problem with my logic or caused by something else in the application.

**The Code**

```
    //Set the state to undefined initial, it'll
    const [ppChanged, setPPStatus] = useState(undefined);
    function checkPrivacyPolicyChanged(url) {
        try {
            fetch(url)
            .then(
            response => {
                console.log("Response: ", response)
                if (response.ok && response.status !== 304) {
                    //If the response code is 200-299 (ok status), and isn't cached (as indicated by status 304)
                    //Tell the component that the privacy policy has had changes since the user last saw it
                    setPPStatus(true);
                } else if (response.status == 304) {
                    setPPStatus(false);
                } else {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            },
            //Error handling
            error => {throw Error(error)}
            )
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
    //If we haven't determined the privacy policy state yet, check for it. (Using manifest.json for testing purposes)
    if (ppChanged == undefined) {

        checkPrivacyPolicyChanged("/manifest.json");
    }

    let color = "green";
    //If a change to the privacy policy is detected, give a visual cue
    if (ppChanged) {color = "purple"};
    return(
        <div style={{color}}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

**The Console** (Note the response codes on the right)
[image: Console and Network Tab Output]

Comment: You should consider putting the `if (ppChanged == undefined) { ...`-block inside a `useEffect`-hook. This will likely solve your request being sent more than once. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

Comment: @Stanislas It doesn't seem to have worked.

Comment: Did you use an empty dependency array? `useEffect(() => {...}, []);` (as opposed to no dependency array). Or can you share the code you've tried?

Comment: No, I didn't. When I added it, it solved that issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 304 returned - 200 as fetch result

The fetch standard describes this behaviour [here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-network-or-cache-fetch).

> 10. If response is null, then:

*See [statusses](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#statuses) for a description about `null body status` which are statusses that are `101`, `204`, `205`, or `304`.*

> 10.4 If the revalidatingFlag is set and forwardResponse’s status is 304, then:

> 10.4.1 Update storedResponse’s header list using forwardResponse’s header list, as per the "Freshening Stored Responses upon Validation" chapter of HTTP Caching. [HTTP-CACHING]
>
> This updates the stored response in cache as well.

> 10.4.2 Set response to storedResponse.

What this means is that the `200` status code comes from the response your browser has previously stored and is serving because it received a `304`. This makes sense, because the browser wouldn't be able to give you a response unless it queried the resource again (which is what is trying to be avoided with this `304 - Not modified` status).

### Alternatives

You could keep track of one of the following headers of the request instead and compare these to a previously stored value:

- [Last-Modified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified)
- [ETag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag)

## Request being sent twice

As mentionned in the comments, the solution to this is to use the [useEffect-hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

```
useEffect(() => {
  ...
}, []); // Note the empty dependency array ensures that this code will only be executed once during the lifetime of this component.
```

The reason why this is needed is because during the rendering, this function will be executed more than once (for example, to update the state after a call to `setPPStatus`).

When this function is re-executed, if the update hasn't occured yet, the `if (ppChanged == undefined)`-block would be executed multiple times and therefor trigger multiple API calls.

By using the `useEffect`-hook with an empty dependency array, you ensure that this code will only be executed once.

Comment: Oh wow, that makes so much more sense. I figured it was something along those lines. The reason I wanted to do this in this particular way was to avoid storing cookies or local data (such as the Last-Modified or ETag values) to save myself the cookie policy hassle, and instead use the browser's built-in caching functionality, but as I understand that's not really possible. Is that correct?

Comment: There might be some way using a request directive like `Cache-Control: only-if-cached` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control), but I don't know how well that would work. In general, I'd try to store the value after a user has confirmed the "privacy policy" instead of wether it has been loaded, because a user might have closed the window before it appeared, or the browser could have crashed, etc.

Comment: Noted, thank you so much. You're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue as well but it turned out I was not using the Fetch API correctly.

I assumed that when I awaited the response from the fetch it was actually giving me the response from the server but it is the promise of the response object. My expectations came from my use of the Axios HTTP. They do not operate the same.

This is what I had

```
async function someRequest(){

    const response = await fetch("doSomeRequest", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: 'example@example.com'
        })
    });
    //This showed the same type of response as OP question.
    console.log(response);

    //Do Somethings with response
    
}
```

The part I was missing was `response.json()`. It is literally the first example on [MDN Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Here is the full corrected code.

```
async function someRequest(){

const response = await fetch("doSomeRequest", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: 'example@example.com'
        })
    });
    const data = response.json();
    //It now shows the same info as the network tab.
    console.log(response);

   //Do Somethings with response & data
}
```